# How to copy an image from PhotoChooserTask to a Bitmap

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bitmap, writeablebitmap

I have been attempting to make a copy of a picture that the user selects from the PhotoChooserTask and use this as a background image for a hubtile in my application, but I cannot figure out the properr way to accomplish this. As of now, I can set the hubtile image to the PhotoChooserTask_Completed response but I do not know how to perform the copy action to a Bitmap so that I may save this image for when the application is launched again or reactivated. So far what I have is as follows:

I create a custom TileItem class to manage the data for my HubTiles

TileItem.cs

```
public class TileItem
{
    //Old Implementation        
    //public string ImageUri  { get; set; }

    //New Implementation
    public BitmapImage ImageUri { get; set; }
    public string Title  { get; set; }
    public string Notification  { get; set; }
    public bool DisplayNotification
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Notification); }
    }

    public string Message  { get; set; }
    public string GroupTag   { get; set; }

    //for translation purposes (bound to HubTile Title on MainPage) 
    public string TileName  { get; set; }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask;
TileItem tileItem;

public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateHubTiles();

        photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
        photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
    }
```

Next I create the tiles and use a custom Settings class to persist my data (namely the 'ImageUri' which is now a Bitmap)

```
public void CreateHubTiles()
    {            
        List<TileItem> tileItems = new List<TileItem>() 
        {
            new TileItem() { ImageUri = Settings.shareImage.Value, Title = "status", /*Notification = "last shared link uri",*/ Message = Settings.statusMessage.Value, GroupTag = "TileGroup", TileName = AppResource.Main_MainPage_HubTile_Status_Title },


            new TileItem() { ImageUri = Settings.linkImage.Value, Title = "link", /*Notification = "last shared status message",*/ Message = Settings.linkUri.Value, GroupTag = "TileGroup", TileName = AppResource.Main_MainPage_HubTile_Link_Title },
        };

        this.tileList.ItemsSource = tileItems;
    }
```

And then I take care of the PhotoChooserTask handler

```
public void changePictureMenuItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
        tileItem = menuItem.DataContext as TileItem;  //used in PhotoChooserTask_Completed                

        try
        {
            photoChooserTask.Show();
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("An error occurred");
            MessageBox.Show(AppResource.Main_MainPage_ContextMenu_ChangePicture_Error_Message);
        }
    }

    void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {

        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            //BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            //bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            //get the correct tileItem that was clicked and set image source to respective hubtile
            string tileTitle = tileItem.Title.ToString();

            switch (tileTitle)
            {
                case "status":

                    tileItem.ImageUri.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);  //changes the hubtile image to selected image
                    //Settings.shareImage.Value.Equals(e.ChosenPhoto);

                    //Set the selected image to the shareImage bitmap in the Settings class to persist image
                    Settings.shareImage.Value.Equals(tileItem.ImageUri); //not working!                      
                    break;
                case "link":
                    //Same as above
                    tileItem.ImageUri.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                    //Settings.linkImage.Value.Equals(e.ChosenPhoto);
                    Settings.linkImage.Value.Equals(tileItem.ImageUri);
                    break;
            }

        }
        else if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.Cancel)
            //MessageBox.Show("No picture was chosen - operation was cancelled", "Picture not chosen", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            MessageBox.Show(AppResource.Main_MainPage_ContextMenu_ChangePicture_TaskResultCancel_Message, AppResource.Main_MainPage_ContextMenu_ChangePicture_TaskResultCancel_Caption, MessageBoxButton.OK);
        else
            //MessageBox.Show("Error while choosing photo:\n" + e.Error.Message, "Fail", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            //MessageBox.Show("Error while choosing picture", "Fail", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            MessageBox.Show(AppResource.Main_MainPage_ContextMenu_ChangePicture_TaskResultError_Message, AppResource.Main_MainPage_ContextMenu_ChangePicture_TaskResultError_Caption, MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
```

Originally `Settings.shareImage.Value` and `Settings.linkImage.value` are set, but are not changed or updated accordingly in the PhotoChooserTask_Completed event.

Settings.cs

```
public static readonly Setting<BitmapImage> shareImage = new Setting<BitmapImage>("shareImage", new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/shareStatusImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

public static readonly Setting<BitmapImage> linkImage = new Setting<BitmapImage>("linkImage", new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/shareLinkImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));
```

Therefore, the images are only updated (in the PhotoChooserTask_Completed event) while the app is not closed, and then upon relaunching or activation they are set back to the orginial images. How can I coppy these images accordingly so that the selected images from the PhotoChooserTask may then be used permanently as the new `ImageUri` (which is now actually a Bitmap according to my first class) for each TileItem?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you corectly you need to find a way to save the taken Image to the Isolated Storage and load on the applications next launch. Take a look at http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images, it contains complete code to save and load a bitmap image